# Comma-separated values as filter control in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a sheet that has a text field that contains strings of comma-separated values.

I'd like to create a filter control that is smart enough to take those comma-separated values and parse them as individual strings.

For example, I have a field called "Colors" and three rows with the following values:

1. Black
2. Yellow, Blue
3. Blue

Currently, a filter created from this field contains the following values:

- Black
- Yellow, Blue
- Blue

Ideally the filter would contain (and filter appropriately) the following values:

- Black
- Yellow
- Blue

And selecting "Blue" would return rows #2 and #3.

This seems like rather basic functionality—am I missing a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

A [*Long* Data Structure](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6295223) is preferred over a *Wide Data Structure*.

One way this can be achieved in Google Sheets is to first [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077) the comma separated values, then [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) them into individual cells and finally, to [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262) them so that they are all stacked in a single column (where `Sheet1` is the input sheet and `A:A` the range):

```
=TRANSPOSE(
{SPLIT(
{JOIN(", ",Sheet1!A:A)},
", ", FALSE, TRUE)})
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/26a5c9f6-f20c-493a-bc48-69792ee35eaf) to demonstrate, as well as a GIF showing the process:

[image: 6]]